# Spring boot reactive (webflux) support with @EnableResourceServer

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to migrate my existing spring boot 1.5 resource server (oauth2) to spring boot 2.x, while do so i am facing difficulties in providing reactive support for the same. It looks like i can not use reactive webflux when i use `pring-cloud-starter-oauth2`, i have few questions:

1. does spring boot 2.0.3 supports webflux + oauth2 resource servers using `@EnableResourceServer`, is yes then what is right way to implement it?
2. If it does not support, what are other possible options? Spring 5 security documentations says that it does not support authorization server and resource server at this moment.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no.
There's no support to implement your own Authorization nor Resource server using webflux.